# Showing time through Date(): it is not being updated using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to show the time and some date information in spanish:

```
  var date = new Date();

  var hour = date.getHours().toString();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes().toString();

  var day = date.getDate();

  switch (date.getMonth()) {
      case 0:
      month = "Ene";
      break;
      case 1:
      month = "Feb";
      break;
      case 2:
      month = "Mar";
      break;
      case 3:
      month = "Abr";
      break;
      case 4:
      month = "May";
      break;
      case 5:
      month = "Jun";
      break;
      case 6:
      month = "Jul";
      break;
      case 7:
      month = "Ago";
      break;
      case 8:
      month = "Sep";
      break;
      case 9:
      month = "Oct";
      break;
      case 10:
      month = "Nov";
      break;
      case 11:
      month = "Dic";
      break;
  } 

  if (hour.length == 1) { 
    hour = '0' + hour;
  }
  if (minutes.length == 1) { 
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  setInterval($('#hour').html('<b>' + hour + ':' + minutes + '<br>' + '<span class="day">' + day + ' ' + month + '</span></b>'), 60000);
```

When I load the document it works ok. The problem the time is never udpated..why?

Comment: 1) setInterval takes a callback. 2) You never update the Date and so it is always the same value as when it was first assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by @Travis J, `setTimeout` first parameter should be a function. (See [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).)

In your case, you also want this function to recompute the date everytime it is called.

So something like :

```
// Define a function that will update the html from current date
function updateDate() {
  var date = new Date();

  var hour = date.getHours().toString();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes().toString();

  var day = date.getDate();

  switch (date.getMonth()) {
      case 0:
      month = "Ene";
      break;
  ...
  }

  if (hour.length == 1) { 
    hour = '0' + hour;
  }
  if (minutes.length == 1) { 
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }

  // Update the page content
  $('#hour').html('<b>' + hour + ':' + minutes + '<br>' + '<span class="day">' + day + ' ' + month + '</span></b>' 
}

// Call the function the first time (setInterval will not call it right away)
updateDate();

// Schedule the function to be called every minute after that
setInterval(updateDate, 60000);
```